# How can BroadCastReceiver keep listening even the App-Activity is completely killed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I want to build an app which listen to incoming messege,Broadcast Listener will call an Activity to do some stuff,It works fine.
But when the app is killed,Broadcast Listener stop listening.

So how can I keep the broadcastlistener listening to incomingsms? Just like default sms app of android?

This is my Broadcastlistener file:

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //DoSomeAction
      Intent myintent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class); //It will be killed once later.
      context.startActivity(myintent);
      }
}
```

This is my Manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>     
     <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
           </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

Comment: You can use a Sticky service for that. Services run in the background, and a sticky service will keep running even after an activity or application gets killed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,so what exactly my app will work? BroadcastListener call Sticky Service to do some stuff,or use Sticky Service instead of BroadcastListener? 
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Not exactly. What you can do is launch the Service from within your activity, by calling startService(ServiceClassName.class).Then from within your service, you can call the BroadcastListener.

Comment: Ohh I see,I will try it now,thanks again !

Comment: The code you have should start your `BroadcastReceiver` when an incoming SMS arrives, even if your app is not running. You don't need a `Service`. Please explain what you mean by _"But when the app is killed,Broadcast Listener stop listening"_ How is the app "killed"?

Comment: ^David: App is killed mean app is closed,sorry for my word so hard too clear my idea. Look like I registered BroadcastReceiver in coding so when my app is closed Broadcast stop listening. So now I need to register it in manifest right? But I wonder where is my app go wrong,cause' I alrd registered BroadcastReceiver in manifest as u see ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Service, lets call this 'MyService'

```
public class MyService extends Service { 

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Makes the service sticky, so that it gets restarted automatically.
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Your receiver code can go here.
    }
}
```

Then you can start this service from your activity like:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Comment: This answer is useless. OP has a `BroadcastReceiver` in his manifest. Android will start his `BroadcastReceiver` when an incoming SMS arrives even if his app is not running. He does not need a `Service` for this.

Comment: Thanks for helping me both of you guys,I tried it and it works same like earlier I used Broadcast Receiver and register in manifest. But when I'm out of App,Press Home Button and Closed recent app,when an incoming SMS arrives,nothing happen. Cant get information from mylog,or cant Toast,can't do anything. Please help me !

Comment: Of course even when I closed my App in Recent Apps,my Service still running,but I can't catch event when sms arrives. Can someone explains to me?

Answer (score -1):

Calling another method from a `broadcastreceiver` is not a good idea. If you want to do any of such stuff then, do in the `broadcastreceiver` class itself. 
Also put enabled=true for receiver in manifest.